# Is it possible to have a unique tuple constraint in MariaDB that uses specific values?

Tags: sql, indexing, mariadb, unique-constraint, mariadb-10.1

In a MariaDB 10.1 table of 50 columns, I have two columns "code" which is a sequence of 13 random characters and "maxversion" which is a tinyint boolean (0 or 1).

Is it possible to add a unique key or a constraint that says for each code, only one row can have a maxversion = 1? Keep in mind that it should still be allowed to have many rows with the same code and maxversion = 0.

Examples :

This is allowed :

```
code          | maxversion
123456789abcd | 1
123456789abcd | 0
123456789abcd | 0
123456789abcd | 0
dcba987654321 | 1
dcba987654321 | 0
dcba987654321 | 0
```

This is not allowed :

```
code          | maxversion
123456789abcd | 1
123456789abcd | 1
123456789abcd | 0
123456789abcd | 0
dcba987654321 | 1
dcba987654321 | 0
dcba987654321 | 0
```

I suppose this is possible through triggers, but is there anyway to achieve this in a cleaner and more concise way ?

Comment: trigger are the only way to perform complex constraints and check, that is clean and consise

Comment: I would normalized the schema with a proper decomposition.

Comment: This doesn't help you, but note that https://mariadb.com/kb/en/constraint/ suggests that `check` constraints work as of version 10.2.1.

Comment: Since 10.1 doesn't support CHECK constraints I would consider to use `NULL` instead of `0` for maxversion. This will allow you to use a unique index on (code, maxversion)

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have much of a say on the way the database is structured as I'm working on a legacy system...

Comment: `I have two columns "code" which is a sequence of 13 random characters and "maxversion" which is a tinyint boolean`implies that you have full access to this table and not on a legacy system.

Answer (score 1):

When you update your server version to 10.2+ (or any [maintained version](https://mariadb.org/about/#maintenance-policy)) you have the ability to use [Generated Columns](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/generated-columns/) with unique keys to achieve your results:

```
alter table c
 add c_maxversion varchar(13) as (if(maxversion, code, NULL)) unique
```

Because `NULL` isn't a value, there isn't a unique constraint on it, but unique values occur on code where there is a `maxversion` = 1.

ref: https://dbfiddle.uk/XKEGsIjy

If you were doing this problem from scratch, do what Georg suggested and use `NULL` instead of `0` in the `maxversion` column and then you just have `code, maxversion` as a unique index without needing Generated Columns.